Securing Sensitive Data on Raspberry Pi with Fingerprint Authentication
I'm trying to secure sensitive data with a raspberry pi, and make it unlockable via a fingerprint.
From prior research I have found that the best way to do this is using an HSM with these capabilities. The HSM should work so that everything is encrypted up until the point that your finger is scanned, and no sensitive data/keys are stored anywhere up until the point of scanning (not on the pi's flash/SD or in program memory). What is the best way to do this?
Is it possible to use a Yubikey bio as an HSM (via ykman or some other way to communicate with the Bio), or should I directly get a Pi compatible HSM for this (and if so, which one)?
Ideally, this should be completely resistant, so that even with a malicious program on the raspberry pi, or with access to the physical device, there should be no way to read the data without the fingerprint.

Do you also require resistance to a malicious program that remains running until the user unlocks the HSM and then steals data (i.e. device is tampered-with and returned to the owner), or do you only require it to remain secure if the device is permanently stolen? Depending on that, the difficulty of securing it can range from "easy" to "nigh-impossible".

@user1686 The device is meant to be kept on person, so the idea is if someone could steal it they could never decrypt the data. So, my original comment on this post was not considering it being tampered with and returned. However, if this is possible, it would be great if you can give me insight on how to do that as well (possibly with a TEE?). If this would be "nigh-impossible", then its fine if not. I'm really just looking for something that's acceptable by modern standards to secure sensitive data (passwords, files, keys, etc.) for a device like this (hardware data store).

I'm also looking for some confirmation/help with deciding between an HSM (and if so which one), or alternatively (if better) using a Yubikey Bio (and if so possibly point me to the right tools/API funcs for the Yubikey if it is preferred over the HSM).

Or maybe theres another different approach thats best for a device like this

Thinking about my original comment more, a TEE wouldn't be enough, because theoretically something could be put in between the HSM/Yubikey and the PI to intercept the decrypted secrets. So it seems like that would be very hard to stop. If it is possible to do so, please let me know. However if it is at an acceptable level of security for a device like this without the need for securing against that, it is fine without also.
